# Where does amplify grab the value of `amplify env pull <multi-env> --restore` from?

Tags: aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-js

In the documentation:

> - amplify env pull –restore
>
> Pulls your environment with the current
>   cloud environment. Use the restore flag to overwrite your local
>   backend configs with that in the cloud.

My question is, where exactly the cloud at?? The problem that I am having now, is that whenever I do `amplify env pull <multi-env-name> --restore`, it is grabbing a different value on my `amplify\.backend\amplify-meta.json` compared to running `amplify init`.

What I initially did is I mistakenly created and pushed an `amplify auth`, and then I updated it to a new `auth`, pushed it, and published it. Somehow, right now whenever I do `amplify env pull <multi-env-name> --restore`, it is grabbing the old `auth` value. If they say the restore flag is to overwrite your local backend configs with that in the cloud, my configs in the cloud should be the last one that I updated(pushed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. It is in the S3 Deployment Bucket of whatever you set your DeploymentBucketName is, in the `amplify-meta.json`. And inside that bucket, you will find `#current-cloud-backend.zip`. So, `amplify env pull <multi-env-name> --restore` is fetching it from there.  You basically can update that file with whatever you want to. But, it would be safe if you get it from `amplify init` command, and it will create a set of file in your project /amplify/ directory. Zip that file, and update it. Be sure to make a backup of your `#current-cloud-backend.zip`in the S3.

[image]